# Revision number for a new build definition

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is it possible to define an initial revision number for a new build definition?

I'm creating a build definition for existing branches, so I must start the revision number counting from the current value.

Answer (score 5):

Create a build, and hardcode the revision number, run the build through so a build gets created. this will now 'set' the revision number. Edit your build definition again, this time set the revision number to be automatically created, save the build definition.

This should mean all future builds should start from the value that you hardcoded

In the build Definition, in the build number format.

```
$(BuildDefinitionName)_1.0.$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(Rev:.r)
```

would produce BuildName_1.0.YYXXX.1 on the first build with YY being the year and XXX being the number of days since january 1st this year. the final 1 being the revision number. all subsequent builds would increment the revision number so 2nd build would be 2 etc.

so if you create your first build, with a build format of

```
$(BuildDefinitionName)_1.0.$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear).954
```

would produce BuildName_1.0.YYXXX.954

Then reset the build format with the revision macro on the end, the next build created would be BuildName_1.0.YYXXX.955 etc.

Comment: I saw this workaround in a blog, however we have at least 10 branches. I'm trying to add TFS Build Extensions to read current assembly info as a way to automate this.

Comment: @Just TFS, what do you mean by 'hard code', I can't see where you can enter this value.

Comment: FYI This no longer works in TFS2015. I would assume it does not work on VSOnline as well.